# f-string python invalid sysntax

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

I recently trying to learn to code in python and I have zero knowledge in any programming languages our there and I encounter this problem in it, in which I am trying to use the f-string function.

My Python version is 3.6.2

and here's the code that I am trying to run

```
greeting = 'Hello'
name = 'John'

message = f'{greeting} {name}. Welcome!'
print(message)
```

and here's the error it shows me.

```
File "/Users/RQ/Desktop/intro.py", line 16
  message = f'{greeting} {name}. Welcome!'
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I am using Mac 10.12.6 OS version

I also removed the default python 2.7 version in it.

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Your script works correctly for me under python3.6 -- how are you invoking this file?

Comment: The stacktrace you are getting is identical to the one shown for python2 / python3<3.6

Comment: **Do not ever remove** any version of Python that comes with your computer. **You can seriously damage your operating system**, which may depend on that Python in any number of ways that are not documented and can't easily be checked.

Answer (score 1):

The f-string itself is correct. Try to figure out what version of python is actually used.

`python --version`